# Trying to make a matchmaking function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord, discord.js

So i am trying to find an opponent for user based on his trophies, it works fine when if condition isnt run but when if condition runs, it runs infinte loop

````
const UserProfile = require("../schemas/userProfile")
async function matchmake(user, message) {

   let UserProfileDetails = await UserProfile.findOne({ userID: user.id });
   let userTrophies = UserProfileDetails.trophies;

   let userMatched = await UserProfile.aggregate([
      { $match: { trophies: { $gte: userTrophies - 10, $lte: userTrophies + 10 } } },
      { $sample: { size: 1 } }
   ]);

   let otherUserID = userMatched[0].userID;
   console.log("userID -"+otherUserID);
   if (otherUserID === user.id) {
      otherUserID = await matchmake(user, message);
   }
   return otherUserID;
}

module.exports = { matchmake }```
````

Answer (score 1):

If it's infinite looping, it seems that your aggregation keeps pulling the same user as 'user.id', which recursively calls the matchmake function again over and over.

I would try to add a $not condition to your match that checks for the user.id. That way, the aggregation doesn't return the original user.

Comment: so i debugged and found that it was adding userTrophies - 10, userTrophies + 10 into trophies itself and since there was no document of that many trophies it kept taking my document.
i tried to change it like this but it still didnt work
```let userMatched = await UserProfile.aggregate([
      { $match: { trophiesGtLte: { $gte: [ "$trophies", lowerLimit ], $lte: [ "$trophies", upperLimit ] }, userIDSameOrNot: { $ne: [ "$userID", user.id ] }} },
      { $sample: { size: 1 } }
   ])```
userMatched outputs []...which means no document found eh